# Incorrect values in imported json in Vue.js

Tags: json, typescript, vue.js

I have a vuex store in which I have all the translations for the application. Translations are imported from a json file like this:

```ts
import en from '@/locales/en-US.json';

const question: Module<State, any> = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    lang: en,
  }
}
```

Content of the JSON looks like this:

```json
{
  "layout": {
    "sidebar": {
      "title": "Test"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I access the value of title I get this:

```
(ctx) => {const { normalize: _normalize } = ctx;return _normalize(["Test"])}
```

Instead of
`Test`

I'm guessing it might have something to do with webpack configuration but I'm not sure. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to import it like: `import * as en from '@/locales/en-US.json';`

Comment: Importing it this way doesnt help, still getiing the same value.

Comment: Show how you access title value

Comment: `const store = useStore(); 
store.state.lang.lang.layout.sidebar.title`

Comment: you have duplicate `lang`

Comment: That is because of namespaced module which is named lang and its property lang. I'm accessing it correctly because there is no error but the value is wrapped in this function for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

It is because your file is precompiled by @intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n/v/2.0.1

To overcome this issue specify a path for `vite-plugin-vue-i18n`.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(), 
    vueI18n({
      // you need to set i18n resource including paths !
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, './path/to/src/locales/**')
    })
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question, but I suppose that you are using [tm](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#tm-key) function.

Thus, as the docs state in the warning message you have to "... use [rt](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#rt) for the locale message returned by [tm](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#tm-key). see the [rt](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#rt) details."

Docs [here](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#composerresolvelocalemessagetranslation) further state that "rt differs from t in that it processes the locale message directly, not the key of the locale message. There is no internal fallback with rt. You need to understand and use the structure of the locale message returned by tm."

Thus, I suppose rt could help you by getting the translation value instead of the function.