# i18next-vue: calling t() returns function(ctx)

Tags: vuejs3, i18next

I configured vue-i18next conforming to the documentation.
When I use `t()` either directly from `i18next.t` or inside a component with `useTranslation()`, it does not returns a translated string, but a function
`(ctx) => {const { normalize: _normalize } = ctx;return _normalize(["MY TRANSLATED STRING"])}`

**utils/i18n/i18next.ts :**

```js
import i18next from "i18next"
import fr from "@/locales/fr.json"

const i18nCreated = i18next.init({
  lng: "fr",
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
  fallbackLng: false,
  resources: { fr: { translation: fr } },
})

export { i18nCreated, i18next }
```

**main.ts** :

```js
import { i18nCreated, i18next } from "@/utils/i18n/i18next"
import I18NextVue from "i18next-vue"
// ...
await i18nCreated

console.log(i18next.t("home.title"))

app.use(I18NextVue, {
  i18next,
})
```

**Console.log output**:

[image: Console.log]

**Component translation rendered**:

[image: Translation renders a function]

Answer (score 0):

Found it by myself: we were using i18n from intlify, and I forgot to remove some code that was pre-compilating locales...
Found the solution reading [Incorrect values in imported json in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314906/incorrect-values-in-imported-json-in-vue-js).

Removed everything from intlify and now it works well.